# Set column as empty if no file is selected when submit

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP and was trying to do the file uploading. When I try to submit a form without having any files selected, the database will still insert a value to the *attachments* column.

My table picture:

[image]

Is there any way that I can set the *attachments* column as empty if there is not file selected for submission. Below is my code:

**view_group.php**

```html
<form class="forms-sample" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea id="status_content" name="status_content" rows="30"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="section_label">Add Attachments</label><br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="file" disabled placeholder="Select a file"><br>
      <button type="button" class="file-upload-browse btn btn-primary" name="button" onclick="document.getElementById('fileName').click()">Select a file</button>
      <input type="file" name="attachmentfile" id="fileName" style="display:none">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-fw">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="postStatus" value="Post" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**GroupsController.php**

```html
 function postStatus($std_id, $group_id){
    $status = new ManageGroupsModel();
    $status->std_id = $std_id;
    $status->group_id = $group_id;
    $status->status_content = $_POST['status_content'];

    $status->attachments = time() . $_FILES['attachmentfile']['name'];

    $status->target_dir = "../../attachments/groupfiles/";
    //target file to save in directory
    $status->target_file = $status->target_dir . basename($_FILES["attachmentfile"]["name"]);
    // select file type
    $status->imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($status->target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // valid file extensions
    $status->extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif","pdf", "doc", "pdf");


    if($status->postStatus() > 0) {
      $message = "Status posted!";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
      window.location = '../ManageGroupsView/view_group.php?group_id=".$group_id."'</script>";

    }
  }
```

**GroupsModel.php**

```html
function postStatus() { 
$sql = "insert into status(std_id, group_id, status_content, attachments) values(:std_id, :group_id, :status_content, :attachments)"; 

$args = [':std_id'=> $this->std_id, ':group_id'=> $this->group_id, ':status_content'=> $this->status_content, 'attachments'=> $this->attachments];
 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachmentfile']['tmp_name'],$this->target_dir.$this->attachments); $stmt = DB::run($sql, $args); 
$count = $stmt->rowCount(); return $count; }
```

I'm sorry if the question sounded dumb. It would be really great if someone can help. Thank you!

**UPDATE!**

Thanks to the people in my comment section, I finally get to do it. Here are the code needed to add :

```html
 function postStatus($std_id, $group_id){
    $status = new ManageGroupsModel();
    $status->std_id = $std_id;
    $status->group_id = $group_id;
    $status->status_content = $_POST['status_content'];

    if($_FILES['attachmentfile']['name']) { 
      $status->attachments = time() . $_FILES['attachmentfile']['name'];
      $status->target_dir = "../../attachments/groupfiles/";
      //target file to save in directory
      $status->target_file = $status->target_dir . basename($_FILES["attachmentfile"]["name"]);
      // select file type
      $status->imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($status->target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
      // valid file extensions
      $status->extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif","pdf", "doc", "pdf");

    } else { 
      $status->attachments = ''; 
    }
    
    if($status->postStatus() > 0) {
      $message = "Status posted!";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
      window.location = '../ManageGroupsView/view_group.php?group_id=".$group_id."'</script>";

    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any validation around `$_FILES['attachmentfile']`. you should check this is set or not correctly.

Comment: give this validation to your code at **GroupsController.php**
`
if(isset($_FILES['attachmentfile']['name'])){
  $status->attachments = time() . $_FILES['attachmentfile']['name'];
}else{
  $status->attachments = NULL;
}
`

Comment: @AtoliGaming I have tried to do the ISSET validation in GroupsController but it still adds values to attachment column

Comment: what value is it add to attachment column after you give isset?

Comment: @AtoliGaming hi! I have change the code a bit and it works using the isset! Thank you very much :)

Comment: glad I can help, maybe you can post your answer so your question can be reference to others :)